# Conditional formatting for highlighting the rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

If "H" column contains "R", then that entire row should highlight in Red color. similarly If "H" column contains "G", then that entire row should highlight in Green color.

Comment: you need to apply CF rule using VBA? if not, why it's tagged `excel-vba`?

Comment: @simoco, I have tried CF, but didn't the solution,If possible kindly provide the solution.

Comment: it's still unclear, you need pure CF or VBA solution?

Comment: @simoco both CF & VBA.. just to understand the concept.. I don't know about VBA & CF.. that's y asked both.. thanks

Comment: Have you tried something so far? If yes, show us, please your attempt

Comment: I have tried using "Record the Macro" option.

Comment: it's good start, but what problem do you have with it?

Comment: I don't know how to create CF and VBA code.. that's the problem

Comment: here a good start for you: http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel

Comment: You dont need VBA, you just need to set a conditional formatting rule.  They are a little wierd, but allow lots of possibility.  Here is one I use to color a field if it has a value in it if the A column as a value: =AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A1)),ISBLANK(B1))

Answer (score 1):

If you want the CF to commence from Row 1, select H1 and select CF.
Select "New Rule", select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".
Enter in the formula box =$H1="R". Set your format fill colour to suit (Red), click OK.
Keeping H1 selected go to CF and "Manage Rules", make sure "current selection" is in the top box and select "New Rule". select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
Enter in the formula box =$H1="G". Set your format fill colour to suit (Green), click OK.
This should take you back to "Manage Rules". On the right hand side check the "stop if true" button for the first condition and select "OK". confirm by testing H1 with "R" and "G".
You should now be back at H1 in the worksheet. Select "Format Painter" to copy format to clipboard and then select the row number on the extreme left, this will paste that formatting to the **entire** row.
Select that row, click the Format painter again then select the number of rows using the extreme left row numbers to the extent you want.
It won't matter if you enter characters in lower or upper case.